# Precision when converting int32 to other types

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision, type-conversion

The code below

```
import numpy as np

i = np.iinfo(np.int32).max # 2147483647
x = np.asanyarray(i) # array([2147483647])
dtypes = (np.int32, np.float16, np.float32, np.float64)
for dtp in dtypes:
    print('%s : %s'%(dtp, x.astype(dtp)))
```

outputs

```
<type 'numpy.int32'> : 2147483647
<type 'numpy.float16'> : inf
<type 'numpy.float32'> : 2147483648.0
<type 'numpy.float64'> : 2147483647.0
```

Now we see `2147483648.0` for `numpy.float32` and `2147483647.0` for `numpy.float64`. I googled and found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

> All integers with six or fewer significant decimal digits can be converted to an IEEE 754 floating point value without loss of precision, some integers up to nine significant decimal digits can be converted to an IEEE 754 floating point value without loss of precision, but no more than nine significant decimal digits can be stored. As an example, the 32-bit integer 2,147,483,647 converts to 2,147,483,650 in IEEE 754 form.

which mentioned another value `2,147,483,650`.

I'm not clear about how this happens. `float32` is valid up to `3.402823e38`, much beyond the max `int32`. And `float64` can give the exact value.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Emmm..... after reading the comments below, I began to read more stuff about how int and float numbers are represented in binary. I haven't make this very clear.

Maybe someone can talk about how to get the precision/resolution of float numbers in a more general extent, which is also useful for understanding the problem of the original Q.

```
print np.finfo(np.float32)
[out]:
Machine parameters for float32
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision=  6   resolution= 1.0000000e-06
machep=   -23   eps=        1.1920929e-07
negep =   -24   epsneg=     5.9604645e-08
minexp=  -126   tiny=       1.1754944e-38
maxexp=   128   max=        3.4028235e+38
nexp  =     8   min=        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Actually, `float32` being valid for up to `3.402823e38` means that it can contain 38 decimal places.

Comment: About `2,147,483,650`:  sometimes wikipedia is wrong.  Someone noted this in the "Talk" section of the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision

Comment: @Jossie Calderon: A `float32` certainly cannot represent 38 decimal digits of accuracy. It can represent values of that magnitude with 23 bits to represent the mantissa. Think about it: A 32 bit float must represent few decimal digits of accuracy than a 32 bit int because some of the bits are use to represent magnitudes (8 bits in this case)

Comment: Dang, @dawg. That makes sense!

Comment: Just for reference, a `float64` can hold up to a 53-bit integer exactly without rounding.

Comment: @dawg you can actually get 24 bits out of those 23, because for a normalized number the upper bit is always 1; because it's constant it doesn't need to be stored, and the format takes advantage of that.

Comment: @MarkRansom: True, but still a 32 bit float cannot fully represent a 32 bit int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point values consist of two parts, an integer and an exponent. To get the value, you take 2 to the power of the exponent and multiply it by the integer part.

For an IEEE 32-bit floating point value, the integer part is [only 24 bits long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats). Larger values can be obtained by compensating with the exponent, but only if their bottom bits beyond the 24th are all zero.

2147483647 does not have zero in the bottom bits, but 2147483648 does.